# MySQL interpreter calls query without an aggregate function an aggregate query

Tags: mysql

I am trying to solve [this HackerRank SQL coding challenge](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/15-days-of-learning-sql/problem). We have two tables, one called `Hackers` with columns `hacker_id` and `name` and another called `Submissions` with columns `submission_date`, `submission_id`, `hacker_id`, and `score`.

One query I submitted to solve the challenge was:

```
SELECT  es.date, es.count, m.hacker_id, m.name, m.score
FROM 
(
    SELECT submission_date as date, COUNT(hacker_id) as count
    FROM (
        SELECT submission_date, COUNT(submission_id) as count, hacker_id
        FROM Submissions 
        GROUP BY submission_date, hacker_id
    ) f 
    HAVING count >=1
) es
JOIN (
    SELECT s.submission_date as date, s.hacker_id, h.name, s.score
    FROM Submissions s 
    JOIN Hackers h ON h.hacker_id = s.hacker_id 
    JOIN (SELECT submission_date, MAX(score) as score FROM Submissions GROUP BY submission_date) foo ON foo.submission_date = s.submission_date
    WHERE s.score = foo.score 
) m 
ON es.date = m.date
ORDER BY es.date
```

However, I got back the error:

```
ERROR 1140 (42000) at line 1: In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'f.submission_date'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

This really confused me since I didn't use an aggregate function in my query. Why did the interpreter give this error, and what should I think about to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

There are two columns named count in first subquery. One is count of field submission_id and second is count of hacker_id. As I understood query needs to perform selection of submission_dates where count greater than or equal to 1. So depends on which count is presumed to be greater than or equal to 1, the query might be rewritten as following:

1) If it is needed that count(submission_id) greater than or equal to 1:

```
SELECT  es.date, es.count, m.hacker_id, m.name, m.score
FROM 
(
SELECT submission_date as date, COUNT(hacker_id) as count
FROM (
    SELECT submission_date, COUNT(submission_id) as count, hacker_id
    FROM Submissions 
    GROUP BY submission_date, hacker_id
) f 
WHERE f.count >=1
GROUP BY submission_date
) es
JOIN (
   SELECT s.submission_date as date, s.hacker_id, h.name, s.score
   FROM Submissions s 
JOIN Hackers h ON h.hacker_id = s.hacker_id 
JOIN (SELECT submission_date, MAX(score) as score FROM Submissions GROUP BY submission_date) foo ON foo.submission_date = s.submission_date
WHERE s.score = foo.score 
) m 
ON es.date = m.date
ORDER BY es.date
```

2) the count(hacker_id) is greater than or equal to 1:

```
SELECT  es.date, es.count, m.hacker_id, m.name, m.score
FROM 
(
SELECT submission_date as date, COUNT(hacker_id) as count
FROM (
    SELECT submission_date, COUNT(submission_id) as count, hacker_id
    FROM Submissions 
    GROUP BY submission_date, hacker_id
) f 
GROUP BY submission_date
HAVING count(hacker_id) >= 1
) es
JOIN (
   SELECT s.submission_date as date, s.hacker_id, h.name, s.score
   FROM Submissions s 
JOIN Hackers h ON h.hacker_id = s.hacker_id 
JOIN (SELECT submission_date, MAX(score) as score FROM Submissions GROUP BY submission_date) foo ON foo.submission_date = s.submission_date
WHERE s.score = foo.score 
) m 
ON es.date = m.date
ORDER BY es.date
```

The problem is that in subquery the aggregated function count(hacker_id) was used without "group by" section with column "submission_date" defined there as nonaggregated column.
Still I'm not sure that the sql-query is logically correct.